# Azure DevOps web.config transformation occurs in pipeline but is not copied to web root

Tags: azure-devops, web-config

This seems like an unusual issue, where the web.config transformation is actually occurring, but the result is not being copied to the web root.

Example line from web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
```

Example line from web.release.config:

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

Things I've checked:

1. Pipieline definitely has all files available, working folder contains:

   ```
   web.config
   web.Debug.config
   web.Release.config
   ```
2. According to the pipeline logs, transformation does occur:

   ```
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8206023Z PreTransformWebConfig:
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8206775Z   Found The following for Config tranformation:
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8207287Z   web.config
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8207966Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\s\Integral.Web.AlbertSite\obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\".
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8249474Z   Copying web.config to obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\web.config.
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8259591Z   Copying D:\a\1\s\Integral.Web.AlbertSite\Web.Release.config to obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\assist\web.config.
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8293749Z TransformWebConfigCore:
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8294503Z   Transforming Source File: D:\a\1\s\Integral.Web.AlbertSite\web.config
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8463519Z     Applying Transform File: D:\a\1\s\Integral.Web.AlbertSite\Web.Release.config
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.8893847Z     Output File: obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\web.config
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.9111483Z   Transformation succeeded
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.9149601Z PostTransformWebConfig:
   2022-07-27T21:12:39.9150514Z   Transformed web.config using D:\a\1\s\Integral.Web.AlbertSite\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\web.config.
   ```
3. Viewed the file `obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\web.config` on the production server, and it is all correctly transformed.

So the transformation occurs, with the resulting correct web.config in `obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\web.config` on the server. However, the web.config file in the root folder *remains untransformed*.

It's like there should have been an extra step of copying the transformed file to the web root, which did not occur. Am I missing a flag or instruction in the YAML which fixes this?

The YAML is below:

```
trigger:
- deploy-production

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

# Install nuget and get solution dependencies.
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

# Build solution.
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    vsVersion: '16.0'
    clean: false
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeleteExistingFiles=False /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# Deploy files to the staging slot.
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Pay-As-You-Go (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'tulips-webapp-production'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'Tulips-AusEast'
    SlotName: 'staging'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Tulips.WebApp'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: false
    RenameFilesFlag: false

# Swap the staging slot into production.
- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Pay-As-You-Go (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)'
    Action: 'Swap Slots'
    WebAppName: 'tulips-webapp-production'
    ResourceGroupName: 'Tulips-AusEast'
    SourceSlot: 'staging'
```

I'm thinking of simply adding a step to copy `obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\web.config` to the root, before the "Deploy files to the staging slot" step. This seems hacky though, so I'm wondering if I've missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at where you're publishing your outputs to versus where you're deploying from. They are different locations.

`/p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"`

versus

`packageForLinux: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Tulips.WebApp'`

You're building a publish package, then completely ignoring that publish package and deploying something else.